# Dimensional countdown

Tags: code-golf, string

**Write a function f(n,k) that displays the k-dimensional countdown from n.**

A 1-dimensional countdown from 5 looks like

```
 54321
```

A 2-dimensional countdown from 5 looks like

```
 54321
 4321
 321
 21
 1
```

Finally, a 3-dimensional countdown from 5 looks like

```
 54321
 4321
 321
 21
 1
 4321
 321
 21
 1
 321
 21
 1
 21
 1
 1
```

### Formal definition

The 1-dimensional countdown from any n is a single line with the digits n, n-1,...,1 concatenated (followed by a newline).

For any k, the k-dimensional countdown from 1 is the single line

```
 1
```

For n > 1 and k > 1, a k-dimensional countdown from n is a (k-1)-dimensional countdown from n followed by a k-dimensional countdown from n-1.

### Input

Two positive integers k and n <= 9, in any format you choose.

### Output

The k-dimensional countdown from n, with a newline after each 1-dimensional countdown. Extra newlines are permitted in the output.

### Scoring

Standard golf scoring.

### Bonus example

Here's an example with k > n, a 4-dimensional countdown from 3 (with extra comments that are not to be included in actual solutions):

```
 -- 3-dimensional countdown from 3
 321
 21
 1
 21
 1
 1
 -- 4-dimensional countdown from 2:
 ---- 3-dimensional countdown from 2:
 21
 1
 1
 ---- 4-dimensional countdown from 1:
 1
```

**Clarifications:**

Digits on a line do not need to be adjacent, but they must be evenly-spaced.

You may write a full program instead of just a function, if you prefer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the test cases correctly. Are the 3D and 4D countdowns from 2 identical?

Comment: @Dennis I think the intention is that 4D countdown from 2 = 3D countdown from 2 + 4D countdown from 1

Comment: shouldn't it say 3d countdown from one?

Comment: *Extra newlines are permitted in the output.* Does that refer to *trailing* newlines or can they occur anywhere?

Comment: @Dennis Extra newlines can occur anywhere. Well, 543\n21 isn't okay, but after any '1' they're okay.

Answer (score 15):

## Python, 60 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k:n>1<k and f(n,k-1)+f(n-1,k)or'987654321\n'[~n:]
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/8vYOFe).

#### How it works

The ***k***-dimensional countdown from **n** can be defined with a single base case:

> If **n = 1** or **k = 1**, the output is **n || n-1 || ... || 1 || ¶**, where **||** indicates concatenation.

Using the recursive definition from the question, `f(n,k)` returns `f(n,k-1)+f(n-1,k)` if **n > 1** and **k > 1**; otherwise it returns the last **n + 1** characters from `'987654321\n'`.

Comment: Dennis is just too good. How did you do it though?

Comment: My only insight here was that you can combine both base cases. The rest is just a direct translation of the recursive definition.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
R¡UḌFṚp⁷
```

This is a full program that expects **n** and **k** as command-line arguments.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UsKhVeG4jEbhuZpw4oG3&input=&args=NQ+Mw)

#### How it works

```
R¡UḌFṚp⁷  Main link. Left argument: n. Right argument: k

 ¡        Repeat the link to the left k times.
R           Range; map each integer j in the previous return value to [1, ..., j].
  U       Upend; reverse each 1-dimensional array in the result.
   Ḍ      Undecimal; convert each 1-dimensional array from base 10 to integer.
    F     Flatten the resulting array.
     Ṛ    Reverse the result.
      p⁷  Cartesian product with '\n'. (Join is weird for singleton arrays.)
```

Comment: Doesn't `Y` work in place of `p⁷`?

Comment: Sort of. For `5, 1`, it displays `[54321]`.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript, <strike>40</strike> <strike>38</strike> 37 bytes

Saved 1 bytes thanks to @edc65:

```js
f=(n,k)=>k*n?f(n,k-1)+f(n-1,k):n||`
`
```

*Previous answers*

38 bytes thanks to @Neil:

```js
f=(n,k)=>k&&n?f(n,k-1)+f(n-1,k):n||`
`
```

40 bytes:

```js
f=(n,k)=>k&&n?f(n,k-1)+f(n-1,k):n?n:'\n'
```

Comment: Save one byte by using `||` instead of `?n:`. Save another byte by using a literal newline inside `\``s instead of `'\n'`.

Comment: Best I could do without the extra newlines was 43: `f=(n,k)=>n?(k?f(n,k-1):n)+f(n-1,k):k?\`\`:\`\n\``

Comment: @Neil I'm using notepad++ to count bytes and the literal newline count as 2 char.

Comment: Maybe you could try it in your browser scratchpad instead?

Comment: Clever, +1. But use `*` instead `&&`.

Comment: I was originally planning to work out a JS submission, but I can't beat this (and I learned a couple of things). Nice work.

Comment: @edc65 It's fixed

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>86</s> <s>81</s> 80 bytes

```python
o=lambda d,n:"987654321"[-n:]if d<2else"\n".join([o(d-1,n-x) for x in range(n)])
```

`d` is the number of dimensions, `n` is the countdown number.

Will post an explanation soon.

EDIT #1: Changed it to lambda.

EDIT #2: Saved 1 byte thanks to @DestructibleWatermelon.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>76</s> 75 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @Sp3000

```python
c=lambda n,k:k>1and'\n'.join(c(n-i,k-1)for i in range(n))or'987654321'[-n:]
```

Caries out the procedure as described in the OP: joins the decreasing `n` results for `k-1` on newlines with a base of the recursion of the `'n...1'` string when `k` is `1` (`k` not greater than `1` since we are guaranteed positive `k` input).

Test cases on [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/xHnZeB)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 57 bytes

```
n#1='\n':(show=<<[n,n-1..1])
1#_=1#1
n#k=n#(k-1)++(n-1)#k
```

Usage example: `5 # 3` -> `"\n54321\n4321\n321\n21\n1\n4321\n321\n21\n1\n321\n21\n1\n21\n1\n1"`.

A direct implementation of the definition.

Answer (score 2):

## Racket 215 bytes

```
(define(g n k(s(number->string n)))(cond [(< k 2) n]
[else(define o(for/list((i(string-length s)))
(string->number(substring s i))))(for/list((x o))(g x(- k 1)))])) 
(define(f n k)(for-each println(flatten(g n k))))
```

Testing:

```
(f 54321 3)

54321
4321
321
21
1
4321
321
21
1
321
21
1
21
1
1
```

Comment: Umm... On 3D mode, why does `54321` appear twice?

Comment: I  am trying to sort out the issues.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ The problem has been corrected.

Comment: Cool, and I also see you removed lots of whitespace!

Comment: In Racket, using lambda (`λ`) is always less bytes than using `define`. Also, the input for `n` was specified to be a number for which you build the `(range 1 n)`.  See also about replacing your `cond` with an `if`, since you save bytes on the `else`.

Comment: I find let and lambda more complex than define. Also, define does not work in "if" expression. I am trying to put these into effect.

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>38</s> <s>37</s> 32 bytes

```
a:":@>@-.~&,0<@-."1~0&(](-i.)"0)
```

This is a function that takes *k* on the LHS and *n* on the RHS.

Saved 5 bytes with ideas from @Adám.

### Usage

```
   f =: a:":@>@-.~&,0<@-."1~0&(](-i.)"0)
   3 f 5
5 4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1  
3 2 1    
2 1      
1        
4 3 2 1  
3 2 1    
2 1      
1        
3 2 1    
2 1      
1        
2 1      
1        
1
```

### Explanation

```
a:":@>@-.~&,0<@-."1~0&(](-i.)"0)  Input: k on LHS, n on RHS
                    0&(        )  Repeat k times on initial value n
                        (   )"0   For each value x
                          i.        Make the range [0, x)
                         -          Subtract x from each to make the range [x, 1]
                       ]            Return the array of ranges
            0  -."1~              Remove the zeros from each row
             <@                   Box each row
          &,                      Flatten the array of boxes
a:     -.~                        Remove the empty boxes
     >@                           Unbox each
  ":@                             Convert it into a string and return
```

Comment: You should be able to use [my approach](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92329/43319).

Comment: @Adám Thanks, I'll try it out

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 18 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Prompts for **n**, then for **k**.

```apl
~∘'0'⍤1⍕(⌽⍳)⍤0⍣⎕⊢⎕
```

`~∘'0'⍤1` remove (`~`) the (`∘`) zeros (`'0'`) from the rows (`⍤1`) (padding with spaces as needed) of

`⍕` the character representation of

`(⌽⍳)⍤0⍣⎕` the reversed (`⌽`) count until (`⍳`) each scalar (`⍤0`), repeated (`⍣`) input (`⎕`) times

`⊢` on

`⎕` numeric input

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%7E%u2218%270%27%u23641%u2355%28%u233D%u2373%29%u23640%u23633%u22A23%29%20%28%7E%u2218%270%27%u23641%u2355%28%u233D%u2373%29%u23640%u23633%u22A22%29%20%28%7E%u2218%270%27%u23641%u2355%28%u233D%u2373%29%u23640%u23634%u22A21%29&run)

Answer (score 2):

## C 93 Bytes

Iterative implementation.

```
m,i,j;f(n,k){for(;m<k+2;m++)for(j=0;j<n;j++){for(i=m;i<n-j;i++)printf("%d",n-j-i);puts("");}}
```

## C <s>67</s> <s>65</s> <s>61</s> <s>56</s> 52 Bytes

Recursive implementation

```
f(n,k){n*k?f(n,k-1)+f(n-1,k):puts("987654321"+9-n);}
```

Comment: You can't declare strings without using char *, so your recursive implementation doesn't compile. But the solution is very easy and saves 4 bytes: just replace `m` inside the `puts()` call with `"987654321"`.

Comment: I compiled using gcc (GCC) 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125).  I think it's ok since I'm just converting from char* to int, however, since your solution is 4 bytes smaller I like it better.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 56 bytes

```
f=->n,k{n>1&&k>1?[f[n,k-1],f[n-1,k]]:[*1..n].reverse*""}
```

#### Usage

When you display any solutions, you should use "Kernel#puts".

Example:

```
puts f[9,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 117 bytes

```
@setlocal
@set/an=%1-1,k=%2-1,p=n*k,s=987654321
@if %p%==0 (call echo %%s:~-%1%%)else call %0 %1 %k%&call %0 %n% %2
```

Port of Dennis♦'s Python answer.